# read IP in html doc from multiple elements

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I have a html doc containing table element.
The table has various properties like  'state', 'port', 'ip' etc.
As part of my academic studying, I need to write a python program that scanning the table and write the data into log file.

I'm using beautifulsoup4, and I managed to write all the properties I needed except the IP.

The reason for that is that the IP divided to multiple elements and there is difficulty to discover a pattern.

Here's the html code (I presented only the IP td)

```
<tr class="" rel="21658486">
      <td>
            <span>
                <style>
                    .pcx4 {
                        display: none;
                    }.AHsU {
                        display: inline;
                    }
                </style>
                <span style="display: none">47</span>
                <span class="pcx4">47</span>
                <div style="display: none">47</div>
                <span style="display: none">105</span>
                <span class="pcx4">105</span>
                <span class="pcx4">164</span>
                <span></span>
                <span style="display: inline">185</span>
                <span style="display: none">238</span>
                <span></span>
                <span style="display: none">243</span>
                <span></span>
                <span class="205">.</span>
                <span class="AHsU">28</span>
                <span></span>
                <span style="display: none">180</span>
                <span class="pcx4">180</span>
                <div style="display: none">180</div>
                <span style="display: inline">.</span>
                <span style="display: inline">193</span>
                <span class="208">.</span>
                <span class="AHsU">95</span>
            </span>
        </td>
</tr>
```

The IP for this (the first) td is: 185.28.193.95

another td is: (can't find a pattern)

```
<td>
            <span>
                <style>
                    .RoUm {
                        display: none;
                    }.LqwJ {
                        display: inline;
                    }.GElR {
                        display: none;
                    }.fOJi {
                        display: inline;
                    }.vLOp {
                        display: none;
                    }.i5lO {
                        display: inline;
                    }.A8Pf {
                        display: none;
                    }.GvPD {
                        display: inline;
                    }
                </style>
                <span></span>
                <div style="display: none">129</div>
                <span style="display: none">131</span>
                <span class="GElR">131</span>
                <span></span>
                <span></span>
                <span></span>
                <span class="LqwJ">189</span>
                <span class="A8Pf">201</span>
                <div style="display: none">201</div>
                <span class="151">.</span>
                <span class="A8Pf">28</span>
                <div style="display: none">28</div>
                219
                <span style="display: inline">.</span>
                <span class="LqwJ">255</span>
                <span class="148">.</span>
                <span style="display: inline">63</span>
                <span></span>
            </span>
        </td>
```

Thank's for ther helpers.
I repeat that this is for an academic studying and no harm is done :)